# Is there a way to add css into during html table to tabulator convert?

Tags: tabulator

I am try to use update tabulator version 4.1 from 3.x. before I am using tabulator-cssClass="hidearrow" into html to tabulator function (3.x version)which is working well. Once I updated tabulator 4.1 that function wont working anymore. is there way to add css class into column header?

I tried tabulator-cssClass="hidearrow"  which working into 3.5

it should allow added css class into tabulator

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug with 4.1 where it is not reading in attributes with capital letters in, it will be fixed in the 4.2 release at the end of the month